# Looking for a Google Fonts like server application that serves right font for any browser/device

Tags: php, javascript, html, fonts, server-side

I'm looking for a server application in PHP, ASP.NET or whatever it's written that serve right font format based on request user agent. Just like what Google Fonts do.

I couldn't find anything online and I'm guessing that somebody should make it, if I want to start making it then when should I start? Do you know good resource for font formats that different browsers accept and also do you know any open source "font converter" that I can use if I decided to make this app?

Comment: Do you mean a free site?

Comment: No, an application that can be ran on my own server

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one for PHP, but I am starting to write one in node. https://github.com/shane-tomlinson/node-font-server

Comment: Adding on to the last comment, it looks like https://github.com/pixline/raclette might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ 
Their @font-face Generator is a good start. Uses CSS, and creates a sperate CSS file, so you just need to call the font family in further CSS calls. It also converts your fonts for multi-browswer suports and creates the appropriate command. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need a special server for this. Browsers should use the first font format they understand in the @font-face declaration.

For example, while I have four specified in mine, Chrome only makes one request (for the .woff file).

Comment: But it downloads other useless fonts too. This is why Google Fonts responding based on user agent

Comment: @Mohsen I'm sorry, but I can't duplicate that behaviour here. Again, I tested this myself just now, and Chrome at least is **not** downloading the useless duplicate font files. What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you send me a live page that is using that method? Maybe I'm wrong and browsers don't download extra fonts. Are you using method described [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/04/05/lessons-on-font-face-from-the-f2e-summit/)?